# Mongo new index on large collection cause instability

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in Mongo 3.2 with >65,000,000 documents.  when I attempt to create a new index the entire replica set goes offline and never recovers until I restart all the servers.

the Replica set consist of a primary, secondary, arb. from what I can see in the mongo log it gets about halfway through index then nothing.

Comment: Did you read the advice in the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#considerations)? A larger oplog seems to be the way to go. Which did you try to create the index on? I think I'd try the secondary first, take it off the replicat set, once it finishes, get it back into the replica set when it recovers you make the primary step down and create the index on the now-secondary server.

Comment: no I wasn't, I was using the { background: true } flag.  my oplog is setup for the default size and the delay between the primary and secondary was nil.  so I figured it would have been big enough to handle

Comment: Can you update your question with the following info: server RAM, a sample document, and the createIndex command you are trying to do? 65m is not that big, it should be flawless